# DNS resolution failed for every tracker

Tags: networking, dns, resolution, utorrent

This is really a weird problem for me guys. My utorrent is not connecting to any tracker. In the logger it says

> DNS resolution failed for tracker udp://........
>   DNS resolution failed for tracker udp://........
>   DNS resolution failed for tracker udp://........
>   DNS resolution failed for tracker udp://........

I close utorrent from the taskbar, and re-open it. Utorrent doesn't connect to the internet. No green check mark or yellow exclamation mark. My downloading starts whenever I see any of the two marks. But this time there is no mark. I have tried reinstalling Utorrent, restarting PC, re-connecting , nothing works. **My Internet connection is fine** Been using this connection for more than 2 years. this problem started from the past 2-3 months. Usually, re-installing Utorrent saves the trouble. But this time not.

The trackers says:

> [DHT] waiting for announce
>   [Local peer discovery] working
>   [peer exchange] working

and "connection timed out" for every other trackers.

Please help.

Comment: Try disabling DNS name resolution in the peers window and in advanced setting.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I don't get it. How?

Comment: Use the settings you have available to you, normally in the upper left corner of the application (utorrent, in this case).

Comment: If it's a laptop with wifi, try it at Starbucks. One guess is your ISP is blocking torrent trackers. Alternatively, swap to Google DNS or OpenDNS.

Answer (score -2):

Simply go into uTorrent and change the download speeds or max # of connections to something lower, maybe half or 3rd of what it is. Then try again. Use the uTorrent wizard if you have to and choose one of the slower connection settings.